# Issue while reloading the json file in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Here is the link "https://github.com/duo-labs/cloudmapper/tree/master/web" .this will run under node.js express. initially, cloudmap.js will be loaded and you can find the file under js. In the cloudmap.js  data.json file will get uploaded. I have given a new button which will reload the new JSON file but when I reload the JSON file it's getting an error 
[image]

Here is the code I have added

```
   document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("click", function () {

        cy.elements().remove();

        NProgress.set(0.1);
        akkordion(".akkordion", {});

        $.when(
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/cm/new.json"),
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/cm/style.json")
        ).done(function (datafile, stylefile) {
            loadCytoscape({
                wheelSensitivity: 0.1,
                container: document.getElementById('cy'),
                elements: datafile[0],
                layout: {
                    name: 'cose-bilkent',
                    nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true,
                    tilingPaddingVertical: 10,
                    tilingPaddingHorizontal: 100
                },
                style: stylefile[0]
            });
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
            modal.style.display = "none";
        })
            .fail(function (e) {
                if (e.status == 404) {
                    alert("Failed to fetch data!\nPlease run cloudmapper.py prepare before using webserver");
                }
                var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
                modal.style.display = "none";
            });

    });
```

I am not able to find how to reload the JSON file. please help me with this issue